# All my Chromium extensions are hidden behind a single drop-down

Tags: chrome

Today I found all my installed Chromium plugin menu have become hidden behind a drop-down style:

[image]

Anyone know how to get them back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Chrome 20.0.1132.57 (and many older versions), if you click on the right boundary of the address bar, between the star and the downward triangle in your picture, you can drag it left or right. The further left it is, the more room you have for icons.

If you want to hide some icons and show others, expand the icon area to see all the ones you want to see, and click and drag to move them around. Shrink back the icon area once the icons you want to keep are on the left.